# Can't figure out what the error is with this method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm passing a hash to this function that either a) has keys that are strings along with values that are ints OR b) it is an empty hash. 
The point of the function is to return nil if the hash is empty and return the key associated with the lowest int.

```
def key_for_min_value(name_hash)
  if name_hash == nil
    return nil 
  else
   lowest_value = nil
   lowest_value_name = nil
  name_hash.collect do |name, value|
    if lowest_value > value 
      lowest_value = value
      lowest_value_name = name
    end
  end
  return lowest_value_name
 end
end
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
1) smallest hash value does not call the `#keys` method

 Failure/Error: key_for_min_value(hash)

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass`
```

Comment: Is that being generated by some kind of test harness? It looks like a unit test failure.

Comment: Correct @tadman I just can't figure out what it means. Why would it think that '>' is attempting to define a method?

Comment: Thanks @tadman ! That helps loads. How can I close this question?

Answer (score 4):

You can't compare `nil` to anything using `>`, it's not allowed, so you either have to avoid that test or use tools like [`min_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) to get the right value instead of this `collect` approach.

One way to make your unit test happy might be:

```
def key_for_min_value(name_hash)
  return unless (name_hash)

  name_hash.keys.min_by do |key|
    name_hash[key]
  end
end
```

Ruby leans very heavily on the [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html) library, there's a tool in there for nearly every job, so when you have some free time have a look around there, lots of things to discover.

Now Ruby is very strict about comparisons, and in particular a `nil` value can't be "compared" (e.g. `>` or `<` and such) to other values. You'll need to populate that minimum with the first value by default, not `nil`, then the comparisons work out, but doing that completely is pretty ugly:

```
def key_for_min_value(name_hash)
  return unless (name_hash)

  min_key, min_value = name_hash.first

  name_hash.each do |key, value|
    next unless (value < min_value)

    min_key = key
    min_value = value
  end

  min_key
end
```

So that approach is really not worth it. Enumerable makes it *way* easier and as a bonus your intent is clear. One thing you'll come to appreciate is that in Ruby if your code looks like *code* then you're probably going about it the wrong way, over-complicating things.

Ruby is an unusually expressive language, and often there's a very minimal form to express just about anything.

Comment: Don't you mean `return nil if name_hash.empty?`? Maybe `each_key` rather than `keys` to avoid the construction of a temporary array.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `return if x` and `return nil if x` are identical. The only reason `keys` is called is because the unit test seems to require it, otherwise you're right, `each_key` could work.

Comment: We know that `name_hash` is a hash (truthy). At issue is whether it's empty. The OP has written `if name_hash == nil` which, according to the verbal description of the problem, should be `if name_hash.empty?`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The rest of the code doesn't care if the hash is empty or not, but calling `.keys` on `nil` is going to fail so it needs that guard condition. I'm just adapting the original code.

Comment: Good point about "The rest of the code doesn't care if the hash is empty or not", so `return nil if name_hash.empty?` is not needed. However, if `nil` is passed to the method we certainly don't want to return `nil` as that indicates that an empty hash was passed. The statement of the question makes it clear that a hash is being passed to the method, so if we want to confirm that we need a first line that raises an exception if the argument is not a hash. I suspect that the OP has confused `name_hash == nil` with `name_hash.empty?`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland All good points. Not sure what the intent is, though sometimes it's valid to be a bit "defensive" when receiving no arguments. Crashing can be a good result, it can show bugs, but it can also be a huge problem in user-facing systems when handling irregular input. "Do the best you can" is sometimes better than "explode".